# Difference between like and = with cell's value =0

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

My query is

```
select * 
from table_name
where column_name is null or column_name = ''
```

However, the result also include cell value = 0

When I change the query to:

```
where column_name is null or column_name like ''
```

cells with value = 0 are excluded.

Data type is float. Why the results are different? Is there any differences when using like and =?

Comment: Tables aren't spreadsheets and they have no *cells*. These are fields that should have a specific type. If the field is numeric *don't* compare it against a string

Comment: BTW what is the table's schema? The query *wouldn't* match `0`s if `column_name` was a text type (varchar, nvarchar etc). If the type is numeric, *don't* use `=''` or `like ''`. Both are wrong, but the first implicitly converts the argument to the field's type before comparison.

Answer (score 1):

[**`LIKE`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) matches on a character data type, and you are comparing a to an empty string with `=` so in both cases, implicit conversion is happening.

```
declare @t table (flt float)
insert into @t
values
(1234567891.123456789123456789),
(0.00001),
(0.00)

select 
    * 
    ,str(flt) --truncates the decimal, only pulling back the default toal length of 10
    ,AsciiDecimal = ascii(substring(str(flt),1,1)) --32 is ASCII decimal for space
from @t
```

As you'll see, this conversion pads your value with spaces. And the clause `LIKE ''` is stating anything that is like a space where as `= ''` is stating anything that is equal to a space. `<space>   0` is like a space, but is not equal to a space.

Remember, `[FLOAT][2]` is an approximate data type that can't be represented accurately. Use decimal when ever you can. Secondly, you could simply use a numeric comparision instead of string ones. i.e. `where column_name != 0`. Since your column is of type `FLOAT` inserting a space would make it 0.

```
declare @space table (flt float)
insert into @space
values
('')

select * from @space
```